# chaining methods what needs to be changed in class

Tags: php

I have the following class and I want to implement chaining methods. I am kinda teaching my ownself so I thought it would be neat to test chaining. However that didnt work. What would I need to do that

```
echo $animal->name.'  says'.$animal->speak()->likes()."<br />";
```

here is my complete code

```
<?php 
class Animal{

    var $name;
    function __construct(){

        $this->name = $name;

    }

}


class Dog extends Animal{


    public function speak(){

        return "Woof Woof";


    }
    public function likes(){

        return "steaks";


    }

}

class Cat extends Animal{

    public function speak(){

        return "Meow Meow";

    }

    public function likes(){

        return "tuna";

    }

}

$animals = array(new Dog('skippy'), new Cat('snowball'));
foreach($animals as  $animal){
    echo $animal->name.'  says'.$animal->speak()->likes()."<br />"; 


}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
class Animal {
  function speak() {
    echo "Random Noise!\n";
    return $this;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  function bark() {
    echo "bark!\n";
    return $this;
  }
}
$a = new Dog();
$a->speak()->bark();
```

You need to return `$this` in order to chain your methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain method, you need to return `$this` in the method for chaining.

Answer (score -2):

try to write instead of

```
echo $animal->name.'  says'.$animal->speak()->likes()."<br />";
```

that :

```
printf('%s says %s %s',@animal->name,$animal->speak()->likes());
```